# Bug in Visual Studio Code, one line of code splits in more lines when I press save

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this problem few weeks, I tried many tings in settings to fix this, but nothing works. Whatever I press save, it split code in more lines, like in the example in photo. What should i do? Here is some examples: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTH4U.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a15X5.png).

Answer (score 1):

There is an option "format on save" that reformats your document. The resulting formatting looks nice so I am not sure what's the problem. If you want to switch it off, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to open preferences, type "format on save" to find the option and switch off the checkbox.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Then you may accept the answer.